# Understanding Gauss Markov theorem

Tags: regression

According to the Gauss Markov theorem, in a linear regression model, if the errors have expectation zero and are uncorrelated and have equal variances, the best linear unbiased estimator of the regression coefficients is given by the OLS estimator. But it's also true that if we omit an important explanatory variable, the OLS estimator turns out to be biased. As far as the Gauss Markov theorem is concerned, how is this possible? Doesn't this example contradict the theorem?

Comment: Both statements are true at the same time, there is no contradiction. An implicit assumption of the Gauss Markov theorem is that you are estimating the correct model!

Comment: To elaborate on @JohnK, the errors are not going to have mean zero (conditional on the regressors) if we do not estimate the correct model.

Comment: Thank you. @ChristophHanck Shouldn't errors have always mean zero if we include the intercept in the model? I don't understand.

Comment: No, the residuals will have, so the *estimated* errors! Whether the true errors, which are unobservable, have expected value zero is something that cannot be inferred from the residuals.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you! Is there a proof somewhere which shows that the errors are not going to have mean zero if we do not estimate the correct model?

Comment: This is not a proof but "correct" model can be understood as if you are modelling the problem exactly with the variables you need, not one more, not one less. Then, you assume errors have 0 mean and have OLS as a BLUE estimator. If you omit one important variable, it can be seen as if you are modelling that variable together with the noise. So previously the noise had 0 mean, but now it won't because the model is not "correct". However I have to say that in practice this is not usually a problem, because there is no "correct" model (that is why I quote it always), but some are useful.

Comment: Thank you, skd. Now I understand. So, since, in practice, we never estimate the correct model can I say that OLS will always have a bias (low or high)?

Comment: If you define the regression model as estimating conditional distributions for a given set of X variables, then there is no "omitted variable bias." The estimates are unbiased for that particular conditional distribution model. Further, you can prove mathematically that the errors are uncorrelated with the X variables in this model (see Rao's famous book), so "endogeneity" is not an issue either.